# valueForKey throws error for optional value, Swift

Tags: swift, key-value

I have simple class `User`. When I try to call `valueForKey` where key is optional value I get an error. See below:

```
class User : NSObject{
    var name = "Greg"
    var isActive:Bool?        
}

var user = User()
user.isActive = true // initiated

var ageValue : AnyObject! = user.valueForKey("name")// OK

var isActive : AnyObject! = user.valueForKey("isActive") //ERROR
```

> <__lldb_expr_862.User 0x7fa321d0d590> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isActive.

If I'll initiate the value, it will work:

```
var isActive:Bool =  true
```

How to make it work with optional values?

Comment: @Zaph I build JSON converter and I need get value by providing the key as String

Comment: Some swift types cannot be represented in Obj-C and therefor can't participate in KVO. Optional Bool is such a type. If you put the keyword `dynamic` before `var isActive:Bool?` you'll see the compiler complain about it ...

Comment: Currently there's no automatic mapping between optional integral types (Bool?) in this case, and Objective-C NSNumbers, so `isActive` can't be fetched with `valueForKey`  When you make it non-optional the normal automatic mapping between integral types and NSNumber works.

Comment: You could do something like overriding `valueForKey` or `valueForUndefinedKey` as suggested by osanoj, but it would be tough, if it's even possible, to make that work for the generic case.

Comment: @David thank you for clarification. Hope in next betas .... :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly why you want to do this and if you really have to use key-value coding, is it for obj-c compatibility?

It might also be something that will be fixed later when Swift is updated. But a (temporary) workaround now could be to override the valueForKey function and take special care of your optionals. Something like this:

```
override func valueForKey(key: String!) -> AnyObject! {
    if key == "isActive" {
        if self.isActive == nil {
            return NSNumber(bool: false)
        }
        else {
            return NSNumber(bool: self.isActive!)
        }
    }
    return super.valueForKey(key)
}
```

Keep in mind that I basically never use key-value coding myself so I don't know if it is a bad idea to override that function... Also in obj-c BOOL isn't nillable so I assume you want false in that case? (For Bool types specifically I would rather skip the optional I think)

Comment: I build JSON converter and I need get value by providing the key as String

Comment: This answer doesn't help me because I write generic form and key will be different.